# Is the attack from Razortooth Goblin a separate action or can I add it to my normal attack?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, sneak-attack, goblin

The [Razortooth Goblin Heritage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Heritages.aspx?ID=18&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) give a jaws unarmed attack that deals 1d6 piercing damage. Can I add this to my normal attack or do I have to spend a separate action for it?

E.g.

First Action:
Attack with my Rapier + Sneak Dmg
Second Action:
Use Razortooth Attack + Sneak Dmg

Or
First Action
Attack with my Rapier + Razortooth Attack + Sneak Dmg

I mean if it would be only applicable in a separate attack why would I ever use it over a standard Attack? So why use a feat for it (except for the flavor)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Think of (racial) unarmed attacks as weapons you cannot lose

You use them *instead of* your manufactured weapons.

[Unarmed Attacks](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=223):

> [...] calculating your attack and damage rolls in the same way you would with a weapon

## Why and when would you use them?

I would only spend a feat on them if I knew that my GM enjoyed taking my weapons away, or if I had a powerful ability that *only* works with unarmed attacks (like Flurry of Blows for a Monk)