# Is there a list of hands-free unarmed attacks?

Tags: optimization, pathfinder-2e, unarmed-combat

For many builds, it is beneficial to have an unarmed attack that leaves the hands free, and is lethal, unlike your fists or kicks.

For example, a Magus might want to have a staff and a shield in his hands, while doing more than 1d4 damage.

Is there a list of options?

Comment: To be clear, you're looking for Unarmed strikes that don't require a free hand - so not claws, punches, talons, and the like. Right? Are you only wanting them from ancestries as well?

Comment: @ESCE Anything that gives an unarmed attack is fine

Comment: So even, say, the Lizardfolk claws?

Comment: Can you clarify the problem you are trying to solve? Are you encountering a situation where your character can't use a hand while making unarmed strikes?

Comment: I think no proper answer can be given unless it is stated what the attack is beneficial *for*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## What I have found so far

### Ancestries:

- Anadi (1d6 piercing, finesse), brawling group
- Gnoll (1d6 piercing), brawling group
- Nagaji (1d6 piercing, finesse), brawling group
- Tengu (1d6 piercing, finesse), brawling group

### Archetypes:

- Ghoul

  - Ghoul Dedication, Claw (1d4 slashing, agile, finesse), brawling group
  - Ghoul Dedication, Jaws (1d6 piercing, finesse), brawling group
- Living Vessel

  - Entity's Strike (1d6 bludgeoning piercing or slashing, agile, finesse, magical), brawling group
- Pactbound

  - Crown of the Saumen Kar (1d8 bludgeoning, shove, trip), brawling group
- Vampire

  - Vampire Dedication (1d6 piercing, grapple), brawling group

### Feats:

- Automaton Ancestry

  - Energy Beam (1d4<sup>1</sup> ranged 20 fire), persistent fire on crit
- Catfolk Ancestry

  - Saberteeth (1d6 piercing), brawling group
- Dhampir Heritages

  - Fangs (1d6 piercing, grapple), brawling group
- Ganzi Heritage

  - Smashing Tail (1d6 bludgeoning, sweep), brawling group
- Ghoran Heritage

  - Hidden Thorn (1d6 piercing, finesse), knife group
- Goblin, Charhide heritage

  - Scalding Spit<sup>2</sup> (1d6 ranged 30 fire) no group
- Goblin, Irongut heritage

  - Fang Sharpener (1d4 piercing), persistent bleed on crit
- Goblin, Tailed Goblin heritage

  - Hard Tail (1d6 bludgeoning), no group
- Fleshwarp Ancestry

  - Living Weapon, Horn, Jaws, or Tusk (1d6 piercing, versatile S), brawling group
  - Living Weapon, Tail (1d6 bludgeoning, backswing), brawling group
- Kashrishi Ancestry

  - Puncturing Horn (1d6 piercing, finesse), brawling group

    - If you have Xyloshi, it deals 1d8 damage
- Kitsune Ancestry

  - Foxfire (1d4 ranged 20 electricity or fire), sling group
- Leshy Ancestry

  - Seedpod (1d4 ranged 10 bludgeoning)
- Lizardfolk Ancestry

  - Sharp Fangs (1d8 piercing), no group
  - Tail Whip (1d6 bludgeoning), no group
- Nagaji Ancestry

  - Venom Spit (1d4 ranged 10 poison), no group<sup>3</sup>
- Nephilim Ancestry

  - Beastial Manifestation, Hoof (1d6 bludgeoning, finesse), brawling group
  - Beastial Manifestation, Jaw (1d6 bludgeoning, finesse), brawling group
  - Beastial Manifestation, Tail (1d4 bludgeoning, agile, finesse), brawling group
- Orc Ancestry

  - Tusks (1d6 piercing, finesse), brawling group
- Ratfolk Ancestry

  - Vicious Incisors (1d6 piercing, finesse), brawling group
- Shisk Ancestry

  - Spine Stabber (1d6 piercing, finesse), knife group
- Sprite Ancestry

  - Sprite's Spark (1d4 ranged 20 type varies), no group
- Tiefling Ancestry

  - Form of the Fiend, Hoof (1d6 bludgeoning, finesse), brawling group
  - Form of the Fiend, Jaws (1d6 piercing, finesse), brawling group
  - Form of the Fiend, Tail (1d4 bludgeoning, agile, finesse), brawling group
- Witch Class

  - Living Hair (1d4 bludgeoning, agile, disarm, finesse, trip), brawling group

### Heritages:

- Azarketti

  - Spined Azarketti (1d4 ranged 10 posion), dart group
- Beastkin

  - Versatile heritage (1d4 piercing, agile, finesse), brawling group
- Goblin

  - Razortooth Goblin (1d6 piercing, finesse), brawling group
- Kashrishi

  - Xyloshi (1d6 piercing, finesse), brawling group
- Kitsune

  - Earthly Wilds Kitsune (1d6 piercing, finesse), brawling group
- Kobold

  - Strongjaw Kobold (1d6 piercing, finesse), brawling group
- Leshy

  - Cactus Leshy (1d6 piercing, finesse), brawling group
- Nagaji

  - Hooded Nagaji (1d4 ranged 10, poison), no group
  - Sacred Nagaji (1d6 bludgeoning, finesse), brawling group
- Skeleton

  - Monstrous Skeleton (1d6 piercing or bludgeoning, finesse), brawling group
- Strix

  - Predator Strix (1d4 slashing, agile, finesse), brawling group
- Tengu

  - Taloned Tengu (1d4 slashing, agile, finesse, versatile P), brawling group

---

1. Enhancement: 1d6 instead of 1d4
2. Only while taking persistent fire damage
3. Seem to be the duplicate of the Hooded Nagaji heritage

Answer (score 8):

## Any Other Body Part

> Almost all characters start out trained in [unarmed attacks](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=223). You can Strike with your fist or another body part, calculating your attack and damage rolls in the same way you would with a weapon. Unarmed attacks can belong to a weapon group (page 280), and they might have weapon traits (page 282). However, unarmed attacks aren’t weapons, and effects and abilities that work with weapons never work with unarmed attacks unless they specifically say so.
>
> Table 6–6: Unarmed Attacks lists the statistics for an unarmed attack with a fist, **though you’ll usually use the same statistics for attacks made with any other parts of your body**.

While the community wiki answer offers a comprehensive list of officially statted-up unarmed attacks, the rules allow for any body part to be used as a weapon.

Being able to headbutt, shoulder, or kick an opponent when your hands are occupied can be very situationally useful, though the default traits for a fist unarmed attack include nonlethal. This is typically only important against constructs with their frequent immunity to nonlethal attacks, but this should satisfy the majority of situations.

Answer (score 3):

### Any and every unarmed attack can be made *"hands-free."*

There's nothing in the rules that says you have to make unarmed attacks with your hands. In fact, the rules say in an armed attack can be made with any body part. An elbow, kick, knee, or head butt are just as valid as a punch or palm strike.

Whether you can be doing some particular something with your hands while performing an unarmed strike is a question for your DM.

Answer (score 2):

## A (Hopefully) Exhaustive Search from the SRD

Archive of Nethys recently updated their search to support advanced queries (hallelujah!). Querying for feats, instincts, ancestries, and heritages that contain both "gain" and "unarmed strike" and do not have any actions associated with it *seems* to have created an exhaustive list. There's currently 53 results, so listing them individually seems excessive. Rather, here's the query:

https://2e.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?q=%22gain%22%20%22unarmed%20attack%22&type=eqs&include-types=ancestry%3Bbarbarian%20instinct%3Bfeat%3Bheritage&exclude-actions=Free%20Action%3BReaction%3BSingle%20Action%3BThree%20Actions%3BTwo%20Actions

(notably, this doesn't get the default Fist unarmed attack, nor the "any other body part" bit @brandon discusses in his answer, but it should get everything else)

Comment: While such a search is an excellent basis and supplement to an answer, I do think listing them somewhere would be useful. Adding them to the CW answer might be an easy and clean option (whether this should just be incorporated into that, I'm not sure). One of the strongest reasons for that, is that your search includes some number of false positives. To my (non PF playing eyes), at least Bullet Dance and Vengeful Hatred don't actually grant unarmed strikes but do appear in your list.

Comment: @Someone_Evil good spot, I can see why that one came up in the search (and yes, your non PF eyes are correct). I'll add them to the CW, but that'll take some time and this link *should* be evergreen, so I think I'll either leave it as an answer or incorporate it into the CW (I'm also unsure which is better - it feels different answer to merit it's own answer, but if the search is wrong... then maybe not )