# Are Tengu Talons hands or feet?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, unarmed-combat

I found the [Taloned Tengu](https://2e.aonprd.com/Heritages.aspx?ID=81) heritage through [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/200677/9552). However, it is not clear for me which limbs are used.
For usual birds, the talons are on the back/lower limbs, but usual birds cannot use weapons or cast spells, so real world analogs do not help here.

Can a Tengu with this heritage attack with his talons if he is already holding a shield and a wand?

(Predator Strix heritage is similarly ambiguous)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Both for the Tengu

> **Physical Description**
>
> [Tengus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Ancestries.aspx?ID=21) have many avian characteristics. Their faces are tipped with
> sharp beaks **and their scaled forearms and lower legs end in talons**.

Strix are a bit less clear from the text:

> [Strix](https://2e.aonprd.com/Ancestries.aspx?ID=40) are avian-influenced humanoids with intimidating talons and feathered wings sprouting from their backs.

But there is two pieces [official](https://2e.aonprd.com/Images/Ancestries/Strix01.png) [artwork](https://2e.aonprd.com/Images/Ancestries/Strix02.png) from the *Ancestry Guide* book they released in  that depicts them with hands at the ends of their arms and talons at the ends of their legs.