# how to increase the range increments of ranged unarmed attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, ranged-attack, unarmed-combat

Some [unarmed attacks have range](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/200673/9552), but the increment is never more than 30 feet. Is there a way to increase it?

[Far Shot](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=502) only doubles your *weapon*'s range, but "[an unarmed attack isn't a weapon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=199)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Class Feats/Features

### Ranger

- [Hunt Prey](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=10) - does not specify "weapon". Doesn't technically increase the range, but does allow you to ignore the second range increment penalty, so it's functionally similar.

Comment: I still haven't found anymore... so this may not be a very long list in the first place.